# File content no section headers

Tags: linux, cassandra, centos, centos7

I'm trying to install Cassandra on Centos 7. But when I want to add below command line to /etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo, get this error:

```
File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo, line: 1
'[cassandra] name=Apache Cassandra\n'
```

Cassandra.repo content:

```
[cassandra]
name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/311x/
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS
```

How can I fix this error??

Answer (score 0):

you should write repo file like below :

```
[cassandra] name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/311x/
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS
```

make sure, you have installed java 1.8

Comment: dear. It didn't matter. Java v.8 is also installed.